# DSharpPlus trying to make a timeout command, but gives "Unauthorized 403" error

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I've been trying to make a timeout command but it won't work.

I've seen youtube tutorials doing the same thing, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Here's the code:

```
    public async Task TimeOut(CommandContext ctx, DiscordMember m)
    {
        if (ctx.Member.Permissions.HasPermission(Permissions.Administrator))
        {
           await m.TimeoutAsync(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
           await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User has been successfully timed out");
        }
    }
```

Adding the command error event just gives me the "Unauthorized 403" error, and from what i saw, that means that the requestor is not authorized tho im the owner of the server and have given myself the role of admin. Also the intents are set to DiscordIntents.All. The bot has admin perms. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Error 403 is unauthorize which means the connection completed and server returned a response.  Timeout is when the connection does not complete or the server did not return a response.  You will not get a TimeOut when you get a 403 response.  You want to capture when the status code is NOT 200 OK.

Comment: You will always receive the HTTP 403 response if you are attempting to timeout a user that has the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission or is the owner of the guild. To test such a command you must use it on an ordinary user. This error is basically just saying your bot does not have the authority to mute an admin or the owner.